# How to put xml tree into separate python file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I use python and xml.etree.ElementTree for building a xml file. But only the base tree has more than 350 lines and I would like to put this in a seperate file. How do I do that?

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

***
mydata = ET.Element('root_data')
version = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'version')
date = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'date')
groups = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'groups')
group = ET.SubElement(groups, 'group')
templates = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'templates')
template = ET.SubElement(templates, 'template')
tpl_linked = ET.SubElement(template, 'template')
--- a lot more lines like this ---
***
```

So I would like to have the stuff between the *** in a separate file.

I tried to call it via a function, but that did not work because then the variables were not known in the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` have a `tree.write()` function to file, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root_data = ET.Element('root_data') # corrected your code here
version = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'version')
date = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'date')
groups = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'groups')
group = ET.SubElement(groups, 'group')
templates = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'templates')
template = ET.SubElement(templates, 'template')
tpl_linked = ET.SubElement(template, 'template')

# For better format
ET.indent(root_data, space='  ')
ET.dump(root_data)

# Write the tree to file
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_data)
tree.write('output_file.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

**Addition:**
Assume you have a file `temp.py`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_temp():
    root_data = ET.Element('root_data')
    version = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'version')
    date = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'date')
    groups = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'groups')
    group = ET.SubElement(groups, 'group')
    templates = ET.SubElement(root_data, 'templates')
    template = ET.SubElement(templates, 'template')
    tpl_linked = ET.SubElement(template, 'template')
    return root_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_temp()
```

This could be imported as other modules, read the [modul documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) or [packaging](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for more details. For example you have another python main file, e.g.  `xml_file.py`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from temp import xml_temp

root = xml_temp()
ET.indent(root, space='  ')
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root_data>
  <version />
  <date />
  <groups>
    <group />
  </groups>
  <templates>
    <template>
      <template />
    </template>
  </templates>
</root_data>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for youre response. I will pickup the learning points from your answer. But apparently my question was not clear enough. I would like to have this code in a separate file (for example xml_stuff.py) and then use it from the main file (my_program.py). Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: @RemcoVroman: If the question is not clear enough, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77799144/edit) the question.

Comment: @RemcoVroman, hope this helps you and you can accept now my answer?